# String correspondente a número real

Tags: java, string, recursão

Estou tentando verificar se uma String x corresponde a um número real (qualquer um). Para isso criei o seguinte metodo:

```
public static boolean Real(String s, int i) {

  boolean resp = false;
  //
  if ( i == s.length() ) {
     resp = true;
  } else if ( s.charAt(i) >= '0' && s.charAt(i) <= '9' ) {
     resp = Real(s, i + 1);
  } else {
     resp = false;
  }
  return resp;
}

public static boolean isReal(String s) {

  return Real(s, 0);
}
```

Mas obviamente esse metodo só serve para **inteiros**, e não **reais**. Poderiam me sugerir como fazer essa verificação?

P.S: Só posso usar as funções: `s.charAt(int)` e `length()` do Java.

Comment: Quando você diz "reais" você se refere a números decimais, tipo `1,23`? Ou você quer algo como o ponto flutuante, que seja aceito pela própria linguagem (tipo `1.23`, ou mesmo `1.2e3`?) e posteriormente possa ser convertido em um número? Dei minha resposta pro caso mais simples, mas ela pode ser adaptada se necessário.

Comment: Sim, números tipo 4.0, 5.1, 1651.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro acrescentar um parâmetro pra sua função, indicando se você já encontrou a vírgula ou não:

```
public static boolean Real(String s, int i, boolean virgula) {
    ...
    else if ( s.charAt(i) == ',' && !virgula ) {
        resp = Real(s, i + 1, true); // Passa virgula pra true
    } else if ( s.charAt(i) >= '0' && s.charAt(i) <= '9' ) {
        resp = Real(s, i + 1, virgula); // Repete virgula
    } ...
}

public static boolean isReal(String s) {
    return Real(s, 0, false);
}
```

Também seria interessante testar pelo `-` na frente. Como isso só ocorre uma vez (no início da string), é melhor fazer no caso base (`isReal(String)`), em vez de na função recursiva.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim, você valida se realmente se trata de um numero e se for, se trata-se de um numero real.

```
public static boolean isReal(String s){
    boolean isNumber = false;
    boolean isReal = false;
    for(int x=0; x<s.length(); x++){
        if((s.charAt(x) >= '0' && s.charAt(x) <= '9') || s.charAt(x) == '.'){ //verifico se é um numero e/ou se contem um ponto '.'
            isNumber = true;
            if(s.charAt(x) == '.' && x>0 && x<s.length()-1){ //aqui eu verifico se o ponto nao esta no começo ou no fim da string.
                if(!isReal) //se o numero ja tiver sido validado como real, ele ja tem um ponto, se tiver outro nao é um numero valido
                    isReal = true;
                else
                    return false;
            }else{
                if(s.charAt(x) == '.') //se for um segundo, ou superior, ponto da string e estiver nas estremidades finaliza.
                    return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(isNumber && isReal) //se os dois forem verdade entao é a string é um numero este numero é real.
        return true;
    else
    return false;
}
```

Como pode ver eu verifiquei se trata-se de um numero, verificando se cada carácter esta entre 0 e 9 ou se é um '.', se estiver dentro dos parâmetros é um numero real.
Não pode haver mais de um ponto para ser um numero valido e os pontos não podem estar nas extremidades da string.

Comment: É uma boa resposta, +1. Algumas observações: 1. "os pontos não podem estar nas extremidades da string" creio que isso depende da definição, i.e. do que o AP quer; na própria linguagem Java, por exemplo, `1.` e `.1` são números válidos. 2. Todo inteiro é real, mas nem todo real é inteiro; um número sem nenhum ponto deve retornar `true` ou `false`? Também depende da intenção. 3. Seu último if..else poderia ser substituído por `return (isNumber && isReal);` (ou simplesmente `return isNumber`, dependendo do item 2).

Comment: Relamente, obrigado pela observação. Minha ideia era que a função retornasse true somente se o numero fosse real, eu verifico se ele é um numero somente para o caso haver uma letra, neste caso eu ja retorno false, se ele for um numero ai então eu valido se ele é um real. Mas Muito Obrigado.